# Make whole div clickable with html & css only

Tags: html, css

I made a box using div and now i need to make the whole box clickable beside text. Current code looks like this,

```
<div id ="rectangle"><div id="iconx"></p></div><p class="rec-text"> <a href="http://somelink.com">LINK TEXT</a> </p></div>
```

div id = "rectangle" is for making a rectangle box. div id=iconx is for icon inside box and rec-text is for padding,styling of text from css. currently only "link text" is clickable. I was wondering if there is anything that can be done to make whole rectangle box clickable.. using css/html only without jquery or js.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Wrap the anchor around the rest of the elements? When you talk about the div being _"clickable"_ are you implying that some action should occur or a navigation sequence should be executed...

Comment: This is what current code is producing. Only text "Questions" is clickable as of now. what i'm looking is to make whole box clickable. Image : http://i.imgur.com/9Sil6Al.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="http://somelink.com"><div id ="rectangle"><div id="iconx"></div><p class="rec-text"> LINK TEXT </p></div></a>
```

Comment: This answer is almost as helpful as the question itself.  Providing code only answers without explanation doesn't do any 3rd party reading through this any good, nor does it teach the person asking the question anything about how you arrived at the answer.

Comment: I know, but such a blunt question does not deserve a very elaborate response.. but not responding such a easy question didint felt right.. so .. blunt question = bunt answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like below

```
  <a href="/divclick">your div here</a>
```

Put your div inside .